# execute inline script from Ajax request

Tags: javascript, extjs

On my application homepage, I built a 'widgets' system. The source of the widgets is generated server side, and pushed to the client through Ajax.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/get-widgets',
    success: function( response ) {
        var boxes = Ext.decode( response.responseText );
        Ext.each( boxes, function( box ) {
            box.id = 'cell-' + box.cell;

            var element = Ext.DomHelper.append( 'canvas', {
                tag: 'div',
                id: box.id,
                cls: 'widget size-' + ( box.size || '11' ),
                children: [{
                    tag: 'div',
                    cls: 'title',
                    html: box.title
                }, {
                    tag: 'div',
                    cls: 'main',
                    html: box.body
                }]
            }, true );
        });
    }
});
```

The problem is, that some widgets have some inline Javascript in their body, that needs to be executed. This works perfectly in Firefox, but does not in Chrome.

Is there a flag or something you need to activate for the inline code to be executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the [`Ext.Element::update()`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.1/docs/source/Element-more.html#method-Ext.Element-update) method features a flag to scan for and execute inline scripts. I changed my code as follows to utilize this method:

```
var element = Ext.DomHelper.append( 'canvas', {
    tag: 'div',
    id: box.id,
    cls: 'widget size-' + ( box.size || '11' ) + ' ' + ( box.cls || '' ) + ' ' + ( box.type || '' ),
    children: [{
        tag: 'div',
        cls: 'title',
        html: box.title
    }, {
        id: box.id + '-body',
        tag: 'div',
        cls: 'main'
    }]
}, true );

Ext.get( box.id + '-body' ).update( box.body, true );
```